# Check if Documents Directory Url empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

In the below code I am trying to check if my Documents Directory Url is empty, so in case it's empty it will show now way or continue to do what ever I need.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)saveVideo:(id)sender {
    NSURL *vedioURL;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
    NSLog(@"files array %@", filePathsArray);

    NSString *fullpath;
    for ( NSString *apath in filePathsArray )
    {
        fullpath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:apath];
        vedioURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullpath];
    }
    NSLog(@"vurl %@",vedioURL);
    NSURL *movieUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullpath];
    NSString *moviePath = [movieUrl path];

    if (videoUrl.absoluteString.length == 0) {
        NSLog(@"No way");
    } else {
        self.imageViewPost.image = [self generateThumbImage:moviePath];
        AVPlayerItem * playeritem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:vedioURL];
        [_player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:playeritem];
        [_player play];
        [self clearTmpDirectory];
    }
}
```

The app crashed and it shows Null value to my Url:

```
vurl (null)
2017-11-29 20:54:24.288473+0400 EasyVideo[43587:2429960] ***
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
 reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
```

I hope to solve this issue.
Thanks

Comment: This makes no sense. You do a full recursive listing of all files and folders in the Documents folder. You then iterate through that entire list and only keep the result of the very last entry (if any). You then assume that last entry is the movie URL. Why do you do this? Your Documents folder can contain all kinds of files and other folders. What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: In " if (videoUrl.absoluteString.length == 0)"  instance videoUrl  and vedioURL are same instance??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first get the data from the URL and check if it is not empty.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
```

Here,if data is not empty you will perform the task accordingly:

```
 if (data == nil) 
  {
       //Do not perform the task.

  }
else 
  {
      //perform the task
  }
```